# Cannot deselect edge loops in blender 2.8 with Shift+Alt+LMB

Tags: interface, selection-tools

Cannot deselect already selected edge loop with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>. The hotkey selects edge loops perfectly fine, but deselection is not working for some reason. Is there a menu where I can change hotkey for it or maybe I need to turn something off for deselection to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem back in 2.82.

I unchecked *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* in the *Input* tab on *User Preferences* which is unfortunate because although I have a three button mouse, I prefer to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to select an edge loop with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd> and then deselect using the same combo in blender 2.83 no problem.

Are you trying to select multiple edge loops? Because that also works fine for me. Could you do a video capture of the problem?